# load folder's images names to a Matlab listbox

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-guide

I'm trying to load all the images' names that exist in a particular folder that i selected using matlab GUI into a listbox.

the problem is that when i select the folder:

if it's empty, I can see the list empty with a white background color (which is the right thing).

But when i select a folder that contains images, the listbox disappears from the GUI. and i get a warning saying:

**Warning: single-selection listbox control requires a scalar Value**

**Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid**

i'm stuck in this issue for a long time, and i couldn't find a way to solve it.

here's the code i tried:

```
 % --- Load up the listbox with tif files in folder handles.handles.ImageFolder
function handles=LoadImageList(handles) 

    ListOfImageNames = {};
    folder = handles.ImageFolder;



    if ~isempty(handles.ImageFolder) 
        if exist(folder,'dir') == false
            warningMessage = sprintf('Note: the folder used when this program was last run:\n%s\ndoes not exist on this computer.\nPlease run Step 1 to select an image folder.', handles.ImageFolder);
            msgboxw(warningMessage);
            return;
        end
    else
        msgboxw('No folder specified as input for function LoadImageList.');
        return;
    end
    % If it gets to here, the folder is good.


    ImageFiles = dir([handles.ImageFolder '/*.*']);
    for Index = 1:length(ImageFiles)
        baseFileName = ImageFiles(Index).name;
        [folder, name, extension] = fileparts(baseFileName);
        extension = upper(extension);
        switch lower(extension)
        case {'.png', '.bmp', '.jpg', '.tif', '.avi'}
            % Allow only PNG, TIF, JPG, or BMP images
            ListOfImageNames = [ListOfImageNames baseFileName];
        otherwise
        end
    end
    set(handles.lstImageList,'string',ListOfImageNames);


    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen to a Matlab `uicontrol` when some of it's parameters are set to an invalid value. Matlab choose to not display them.

In your case, the error message tells you the `Value` parameter is incorrect.

Your `listbox` is defined as a "*single-selection*", which means you can only have one line selected at a time. The `Value` parameter represent the line number which is selected. This parameter has to be a "scalar", a single number, not a vector which would represent several line selected (possible with "multi-selection" listboxes).

Note that Matlab doesn't support an empty `Value` either, so if your `Value` was set to `[]`, it will also error when you populate the lisbox. (*at least not on my R2009a version*)

The simple way to overcome that, is to set the `Value` at the same time you populate the `listbox`:

```
set(handles.lstImageList,'string',ListOfImageNames,'Value',1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Hoki ... that's exactly what i wanted.. it's working fine. appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you create `ListOfImageNames`. The result of your code is a long string containing all the image names without any space or delimiter.
The `String` property of MATLAB's `listbox` expect a cell array with the strip of each line. You can try this:

```
ListOfImageNames =[];
NumOfImages = 0;
ImageFiles = dir([handles.ImageFolder '/*.*']);
for Index = 1:length(ImageFiles)
    baseFileName = ImageFiles(Index).name;
    [folder, name, extension] = fileparts(baseFileName);
    extension = upper(extension);
    switch lower(extension)
    case {'.png', '.bmp', '.jpg', '.tif', '.avi'}
        % Allow only PNG, TIF, JPG, or BMP images
        NumOfImages = NumOfImages + 1;
        ListOfImageNames{NumOfImages} = baseFileName;
    otherwise
    end
end
set(handles.lstImageList,'string',ListOfImageNames);
```

Comment: I suspected that too at first but i ran his code and his list construction works fine. It returns a cell array of string.

Comment: Well, I ran it and it returned a long string and the code produced the same warning as the OP. Perhaps it is matlab version/OS dependent?

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question. I didn't have any problem with my array, because i thought i might have that error, but when i returned it's values; it was working fine. @Hoki gave me the answer. thank you very much

Comment: @ThP. It may be context dependent indeed. I have to say I would construct the cell array differently too. Note that in your way of building it you do not need the `NumOfImages` counter, you could get away with `ListOfImageNames(end+1) = { baseFileName } ;` (provided you initialized it earlier as an empty cell array first, as he did: `ListOfImageNames = {};`)